# Ошибка в fragment, что ставить вместо this?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `Fragment` интегрировал в него слайдер картинок, но возникла ошибка как ее исправить?

Ошибка находиться

> mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(FragmentGyroLoop.this, ImgArray));

Вот что пишет при запуске

> error: incompatible types: FragmentGyroLoop cannot be converted to Context
> mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(FragmentGyroLoop.this, ImgArray));
> ^

Fragment

```
public class FragmentGyroLoop extends Fragment {

    private static ViewPager mPager;
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static final Integer[] img = {R.mipmap.customs1, R.mipmap.customs2, R.mipmap.customs3, R.mipmap.customs4};
    private ArrayList<Integer> ImgArray = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gyro_loop, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ImgArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(img));
        mPager = requireView().findViewById(R.id.pager_customs);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(FragmentGyroLoop.this, ImgArray));
        CircleIndicator indicator = requireView().findViewById(R.id.indicator_customs);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = () -> {
            if (currentPage == img.length) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        };
        //Auto start
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 60000, 60000);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images){
        this.images = images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object){
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup view, int position){
        View myImageLayout  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, view, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        myImage.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        return myImageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Адаптеру для создания нужен объект класса `Context`, Вы, скорее всего, брали как пример создание адаптера в `Activity`. `Activity` является дочерним классом `Context` и подходит в качестве замены, а `Fragment` таким свойством не обладает. Таким образом Вам надо заменить `this` на `requireActivity()` или `requireContext()`

Answer (score 2):

`Fragment` не наследуется от `Context` в отличии от `Activity`. Чтобы получить Context в фрагменте, используйте метод фрагмента `requireContext()`.